# Force Update Id that is a PK Identity

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a problem where I ported over some records after doing a truncate to a table which automatically reseeds the table.

Problem is the Ids I'm porting over are all messed up because the reseed just started from 1 again of course but the first Id I port over is 17 and goes up, skipping some in between.

So the set of records I ported over should have PKs like this:

```
17
18
20
33
... and so on


Right now I have:
1
2
3
4.. and so on
```

again because I did an insert when the PK was still there and only did a reseed when I ported over that first set, I'm screwed.

How can I manually update this table with the PK (the one I ported to) by temporary disabling the PK on it?  It's got some references to that PK also which makes this even more complicated.  I just want to say hey, disable this PK and disable any FKs to it...manually update the Id myself in SQL Mangagement Studio, then enable the PK and related FKs again.

I don't have that many records to update so I can just do this manually.  Problem is the constraint of PK and related FKs.

Comment: Sounds like all the fk values are mapped to the new pk ids. if so why do you need the old pk ids?

Comment: no this is an existing table with PK and related FKs

Answer (score 0):

The quick way would be to drop the primary key and foreign key relationships.  You can do this within management studio.

Once the data load is complete and you've fixed the ids, create the key and foreign key relationships again.

Comment: yea problem is I also have to remove the clustered index I think.  I removed the FKs but it won't let me remove the PK due to an existing index...